# Not getting any output from jobs submitted to thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, static

Say I have class A and class B. class A has just a main method with the following code:

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String xput = "";
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        for(int i = 1; i < number; i++){
            pool.submit(new B(list.get(i-1)));
            xput = B.returnValue;
            System.out.println(xput);//testing purposes
        }
    }
}
```

class B extends Thread, and looks like this:

```
public class B extends Thread{

    static String returnValue = "";        

    public B(String x){
        super(x);
    }

    public void run(){
        double x = 20;
        returnValue += "Grand total: " +
            NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(x) + "\n";
    }
}
```

Yet `System.out.println(xput)` does not print anything except an empty line.  Anyone know why?  My classes have a lot more code than this obviously, but since I'm not getting any output, I'm starting with a small case.

Comment: Your main method doesn't instantiate any `B`'s and we don't know what `list` is.

Comment: You need to read a lot on multi-threading, concurrency and the Java memory model.  Those are complex and subtle topics and I don't think just putting code samples on SO and having people telling you what to do will be much help in the long term.  You really have a lot to learn.  "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Goetz and all is an excellent book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code suffers from a number of race conditions since they are all updating the same `static String returnValue`.  Also the threads may actually not have run yet when the `System.out.println(xput)` is called.  You would need to use the `future.get()` method to wait for each of the threads to finish and you can't do that in the same loop where you submit them to the thread-pool.

Since 4 threads will be running at once, and they all are updating the same `static` field, you need to provide some synchronization around that variable.  What I would recommend instead is to use the `Future` features of the `ExecutorService` instead of modifying the static field.  Something like the following should work:

```
List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
for(int i = 1; i < number; i++){
    B b = new B(list.get(i - 1));
    // submit the job b add the resulting Future to the list
    futures.add(pool.submit(b));
}
// all of the jobs are submitted now
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Future<String> future : futures) {
   // now join with each of the jobs in turn and get their return value
   sb.append(future.get());
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());

// you should implement Callable _not_ extend thread
public class B implements Callable<String> {
    public String call(){
        ...
        return "some string";
    }
}
```

The `Future` features of the `ExecutorService` allow you to get results from each of the jobs that were processed by the thread-pool.  You can `submit()` `Callable` classes which can return a result `String` (or other object) from the `call()` method.

Also, your `B` should implement `Callable` not extend `Thread`.  Although it would work, it is only because `Thread` implements `Runnable` as well.  The thread-pool has its own internal threads and you only submit `Runnable` or `Callable` objects to it.

Lastly, instead of using a `for (int i` loop when processing lists (or any Java collection), you should get into the habit of using:

```
 for(String x : list) {
    B b = new B(x);
    ...
```

If you *have* to use the `for (int i` then at least go from 0 to the `size()` of the list:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
```

That way if you change the size of list you don't have to remember to change your loop as well.

Comment: How would I set it up so that the statement prints after the threads have run?

Comment: I've added that to my answer @user1261445.  With the Future you can get the result from the `call()` method and build your result string.  t the end you just print the `sb.toString()`

Comment: +1. nice edits. turned this answer from a ok answer to a great one!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is being printed because you are checking your 'returnValue' before it is getting set. Having the 'returnValue' static also means that all threads will be writing to the same shared variable.

If you want to have a return value for your threads, have them implement `callable<T>` instead of thread, and pass them to the `<T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)` method. call `get()` on the `Future<T>` returned for the value you are looking for.